# Plotting same coefficient over time

Tags: stata, coefplot

I am using the `coefplot` package in Stata to plot how a coefficient changes depending on the model employed. In particular, I want to see how the coefficient of interest changes over time. I am plotting it vertically, so the x-axis could show the year to which each coefficient refers to. However, I am not able to label the x-axis accordingly (instead of showing the name of the variable I am interested, `x1`, it should state 1, 2 and 3. I would also like to omit the legend by using the option `legend(off)` but that does not work.

This is the code I am using:

```
reg y x1 x2 if year==1;
estimates store t1;

reg y x1 x2 if year==2;
estimates store t2;

reg y x1 x2 if year==3;
estimates store t3;

coefplot t1 t2 t3, drop(x2) vertical yline(0);
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have inserted `if` in your `regress` commands; they could not possibly work otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nonsensical example that uses two categories (and not time) can be easily adapted:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto

reg price weight rep78 if foreign
estimates store foreign

reg price weight rep78 if !foreign
estimates store not_foreign

matrix at = (1 / 2)

coefplot foreign || not_foreign, drop(rep78 _cons) vertical bycoefs
```

You can build the syntax within a loop, using a `local`. Then feed it to `coefplot`. To be precise, I mean something like the exemplary syntax:

```
year1 || year2 || ... || yearn
```

The final command would look something like:

```
coefplot `allyears', drop(<some_stuff>) vertical bycoefs
```

A complete example that does involves time:

```
clear
set more off

use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/nlswork.dta

forvalues i = 70/73 {
    regress ln_w grade age if year == `i'
    estimates store year`i'
    local allyears `allyears' year`i' ||
    local labels `labels' `i'
}

// check
display "`allyears'"
display `"`labels'"'

coefplot `allyears', keep(grade) vertical bycoefs bylabels(`labels')
```

If `coefplot` doesn't turn out to be flexible enough, you can always try with `statsby` and `graph` commands (`help graph`).

Comment: Following on that, instead of "year70", "year71" and so on, would it be possible that the x-axis shows only "70", "71", "72" and "73"?

Comment: Those are not valid names for `estimates store`, but you can use the `bylabels()` option. I edited my answer.

Comment: Brilliant!! This is the final code in case other users may find it useful: 
reg y x1 x2 if year==1;
estimates store t1;

reg y x1 x2 if year==2;
estimates store t2;

reg y x1 x2 if year==3;
estimates store t3;

coefplot t1 || t2 || t3, drop(x2) vertical bycoefs bylabels(1 2 3) yline(0);

Comment: You can **accept** and **upvote** the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I have tried the exact same thing, but I have 200 years worth of data. In this event, I have replicated your code exactly, but for some reason, the local variable allyears does not store all the different year values. If I restrict the sample to just 10 years for instance, it works perfectly. Do you have any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: @ChinG, It works just fine if you susbstitute for `i = 1800/2018` in the `forvalues` loop (run only the loop without the `regress` and `estimates` commands and check using the `display` commands). If not, than you should post a new question with the code you're running in order for someone to help.

Comment: If I try running the suggested code but without the  " | | " separator in coefplot (to have all coefficients in the same plot), the solution no longer works. Is there a way to achieve the same result for this case?