# How to get multiple coefficients on same graph

Tags: plot, graphics, stata, coefficients

In Stata, I am using the `coefplot` package to try and plot one coefficient from multiple regressions (in other words, there will be multiple coefficients, but each one comes from a different regression) on the same plot.

Here is code (related to [Plotting same coefficient over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068430/plotting-same-coefficient-over-time/33070216#33070216)) that accomplishes this *when the coefficients have the same name in each regression*:

```
ssc install coefplot
sysuse auto, clear
estimates clear
regress price mpg if foreign==0
est sto t1
regress price mpg if foreign==1
est sto t2
regress price mpg if rep78==5
est sto t3
coefplot t1 || t2 || t3, drop(_cons) vertical bycoefs yline(0)
```

This is all fine and dandy. But how can I accomplish the same thing when the coefficient from each regressions relates to a different variable? For example:

```
estimates clear
regress price mpg if foreign==0
est sto t1
regress price trunk if foreign==1
est sto t2
regress price weight if rep78==5
est sto t3
coefplot t1 || t2 || t3, drop(_cons) vertical bycoefs yline(0)
```

This produces three separate plots when I want just one plot. What do I need to do to accomplish this? What I would like is for there to be one plot with the coefficients from `mpg` (`t1`), `truck` (`t2`), and `weight` (`t3`) all plotted on the same plot. It would be good to know also how to switch between labeling these coefficients `mpg, truck, weight` and `t1, t2, t3`.

One solution is to use a matrix, but I would like to avoid going down this route if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: `coefplot` is a user-written command.

An example below:

```
sysuse auto, clear

estimates clear

regress price mpg if foreign==0
est sto t1

regress price trunk if foreign==1
est sto t2

regress price weight if rep78==5
est sto t3

coefplot (t1\t2\t3), drop(_cons) xline(0)
```

Apart from the usual `help`, check also [this document](ftp://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/files/wp1/jann-2013-coefplot.pdf) by Ben Jann, the command's author.

Comment: Super! Is there a way to label the coefficients as `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, as opposed to `Mileage (mpg)`, etc.?

Comment: Yes. Check the `coeflabels()` or `asequation` options.

Comment: Thanks! I found that this combination does the trick: `asequation swapnames noeqlabels`.